# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this.state.products.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import './StoreFront.css';

class StoreFront extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
        products: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("url")
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                products: response
            })
        })
}

render() {
    let productDisplay = this.state.products.map((element, index) => {
        return (
            <div className="product-container" key={index}>
                <h2>{element.title}</h2>
                <img src={element.image} alt="" />
                <h2>{element.desc}</h2>
                <h3>{"$" + element.price + ".00"}</h3>
                <button onClick={() => this.props.addToShoppingCart(element)}>Purchase!</button>
            </div>
        )
    })
    return (
        <div className="storefront-container">
            {productDisplay}
        </div>
    )
}
}

 export default StoreFront;
```

I've looked all over and when console logged I'm getting a bunch of objects back inside of the products array. I have used the debugger inside of chrome and the bug always starts at link 24 or "let productDisplay = this.state.products.map"
i can put an object inside of products like this products: [{}] but when done the values are undefined. Most responses in google are dealing with .json packages or setting items to be strings and acting as if they are arrays still.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `this.state.products` isn't an array.

The only time where this can happen is in this part of the code.

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get("url")
        .then((response) => {
            this.setState({
                products: response
            })
        })
}
```

Where the `response` might be an object and not an array.

I'm not sure what you want to do, but maybe you can add the response in the array.

```
let newProducts = [...this.state.products]
newProducts.push(response)
this.setState({
    products: newProducts 
})
```

To solve this problem in the correct way, please add to your questions what is comming in the `response` of the `axios` call.

**Edit:** as [antoinechalifour](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2858250/antoinechalifour) said in the comments:

> Since they are using Axios, I guess it should be products: `response.data` where data is the actual products array.

This is also a possible solution.

Comment: Since they are using Axios, I guess it should be `products: response.data` where data is the actual products array

Comment: I fixed my code, turns out the url was missing a / at the end. Thank you!

Comment: If `response` is not an array, then you likely cannot do `[...response]` either.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the state of products is not an array.
You can check if the products array exist before setting the state again.

Like this

```
this.setState({
    products: {...this.state.products ? this.state.products : '', response}
})
```